# setState interrupted by a method passed in props which sets state of parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building todo app in react and I have a problem with updating state of children and parent component (via method passed in by a prop) in a same time. When I click on edit button in single-task.js, I want to trigger setState({isEditing: true}) and this.props.globalEditingToggle(); (passed by app.js through list.js). And it have been working perfectly, untill I realized that I have made a mistake in setting key value in list.js. I used to set it like this: key={i}. Then I switched it to unique id with use of [shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid). And with unique key only this.props.globalEditingToggle(); triggers. Why is it like that and what can be a solution?

Here is a code:

app.js:

```
import {List} from './list';

export class App extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        tasks: [['Task no.1',false],['Task no.2',true],['Task no.3',false]],
        isGlobalEditing: false,

    }
    this.globalEditingToggle=this.globalEditingToggle.bind(this);
    this.updateTasks=this.updateTasks.bind(this);
    this.delete=this.delete.bind(this);
}

globalEditingToggle(){
    let newState=this.state.isGlobalEditing===false?true:false;
    this.setState({isGlobalEditing: newState});
}

updateTasks(input,item){
    if(this.state.isAdding){
        this.addingToggle();
        const updatedTasks=this.state.tasks;
        updatedTasks.push([input, false]);
        this.setState({tasks: updatedTasks});
    }else{
        const updatedTasks=this.state.tasks;
        updatedTasks.splice(item,1,input);
        this.setState({tasks: updatedTasks});
    }
}

delete(e){
    const item=e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    const updatedTasks=this.state.tasks;
    updatedTasks.splice(item,1);
    this.setState({tasks: updatedTasks});
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className='gridContainer'>
            <div className='gridHeader'>
                <h1 className='title'>Tasks to do</h1>
            </div>
            <List
                tasks={this.state.tasks}
                isGlobalEditing={this.state.isGlobalEditing}
                globalEditingToggle={this.globalEditingToggle}
                delete={this.delete}
                updateTasks={this.updateTasks}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

list.js:

```
import {SingleTask} from './single-task';
import shortid from 'shortid';

export class List extends React.Component{

render(){
    let list=[];
    for(let i in this.props.tasks){
        list.push(
            <SingleTask
                key={shortid.generate()}
                tasks={this.props.tasks}
                i={i}
                isGlobalEditing={this.props.isGlobalEditing}
                globalEditingToggle={this.props.globalEditingToggle}
                updateTasks={this.props.updateTasks}
                delete={this.props.delete}
            />
        );
    }
    return(
        <div className='gridMain'>
            {list}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

single-task.js:

```
export class SingleTask extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        isEditing: false
    }
    this.editOn=this.editOn.bind(this);
    this.editOff=this.editOff.bind(this);
    this.save=this.save.bind(this);
}

editOn(){
    this.setState({isEditing: true});
    this.props.globalEditingToggle();
}

editOff(){
    this.setState({isEditing: false});
    this.props.globalEditingToggle();
}

save(e){
    const newText=e.target.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.editField').value;
    const status=this.props.tasks[e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id][1];
    const item=e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    this.props.updateTasks([newText, status],item);
    this.editOff();
}

render(){
    if(this.state.isEditing){
        return (
        <div id={this.props.i} className='taskContainer'>
            <label className='check'>
                <input type='checkbox'/>
            </label>
            <input type='text' defaultValue={this.props.tasks[this.props.i][0]} className='editField'/>
            <div className='menu'>
                <button onClick={this.save}>Save</button>
                <button onClick={this.editOff}>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }else{
        return (
        <div id={this.props.i} className='taskContainer'>
            <label className='check'>
                <input type='checkbox'/>
            </label>
            <span className='main'>{this.props.tasks[this.props.i]}</span>
            <div className='menu'>
                <button onClick={this.editOn}>Edit</button>
                <button onClick={this.props.delete}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: so u r telling that your `globaledit` function triggers but nothing happens right ?

Comment: globalEditToggle triggers and works fine, but setState placed in editOn() function is not triggering. Also I tried to setState and then trigger this.props.globalEditingToggle in setTimeout, but after that time I got message that this function is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`key` is used by React to map a DOM element to its virtual DOM element. When your `<List>` renders, the key you are trying to set is `key={shortid.generate()}`. So each time a new key is set and the old element is removed and a new element is mounted.

Since a new element is mounted again, your state is set to its initial state. To further confirm if the component is unmounted and mounted again, you may try `console.log` in the respective functions under `SingleTask`.

Solution is that you have to use `shortid` to generate an `id` for a `task` only once, preferably when you are creating the task(and also when you are initializing tasks in the state initially).

Answer (score 0):

I think what happen is that you call `shortid` on render, instead using it when you creating your tasks.

In your case for every change in the `<App />` component your whole list will re-render and because every re-render will generate unique ids for `<SingleTask />`s components you will un-mount and mount a completely new `<SingleTask />`s elements, so in any one of them you will get the initial state: `{ isEditing: false }`.